# little regexp javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:

```
/a/b/([^\/]+)(\?id=1)?
```

The match for the first captured group is /a/b/**search?id=1**.

Currently, `Regexp.$1=search?id=1`, but I would like `Regexp.$1=search`.

Comment: _...only the word search.._ ? what does that mean? Can you post your **expected output** so we know what you are talking about?

Comment: for the captured group currently is search?id=1. I would like only Regexp.$1=search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may restrict the `[^\/]` by adding `?` into the negated character class:

```
/\/a\/b\/([^\/?]+)(\?id=1)?/
              ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HMNdvD/1). The `[^\/?]+` will match 1 or more chars other than `/` and `?` and will thus stop before a `?`, that will be matched with an optional capturing group at the end of the pattern.

JS demo:

```js
var s = "/a/b/search?id=1";
var rx = /\/a\/b\/([^\/?]+)(\?id=1)?/;
var m = s.match(rx);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]); // => search
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks I understand now. I have to make it stops with ?.

Comment: @stackk: If you know what you need to do with `(\?id=1)?`, the second capturing group, let me know. I am not sure you really need it and could just use `/\/a\/b\/([^\/?]+)/`

Comment: My requirements was to math  /a/b/search?id=1 or  /a/b/search

Comment: @stackk Then, you may make the `(\?id=1)?` non-capturing: `(?:\?id=1)?`

Comment: @stackk: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) since you reached 15 rep points and are now entitled to upvoting.